# AMSlideMenu Load View Controller on a button

Tags: ios, objective-c, amslidemenu

I am trying to implement AMSlideMenu. My Application flows like this MainVC -> SlideMenuVC -> LoginVC

now in LoginVC if user login button is pressed I want to launch a new VC which should automatically have AMSlideMenu in it. How can I do it ?

[image]

VC with Purple Background is the LoginVC

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the documentation on [github](https://github.com/SocialObjects-Software/AMSlideMenu)

```
You can use AMSlideMenu with both static cells and dynamic cell prototypes.

Just follow this steps:
1. Copy AMSlideMenu/AMSlideMenuForStoryboard folder to your project. 
2. Make a subclass of AMSlideMenuMainViewController. Assume you made MainVC.h and MainVC.m files (like in this project).
3. Add a UIViewController to your iPhone's or iPad's storyboard and name it's class to MainVC and embed it in UINavigationController
4. For Left Menu:
       Add a UITableViewController to your storyboard and name it's class to any class that inherits from 
       AMSlideMenuLeftTableViewController. Connect the AMSlideMenuMainViewController with your subclass with a custom        segue of type AMSlideMenuLeftMenuSegue, set the segue identifier to leftMenu.

    For Right Menu:
       Add a UITableViewController to your storyboard and name it's class to any class that inherits from 
       AMSlideMenuRightTableViewController. Connect the AMSlideMenuMainViewController with your subclass with a custom        segue of type AMSlideMenuRightMenuSegue, set the segue identifier to rightMenu.

5. To add Content ViewController you have to to do the following:
       • Create your content view controller and embed it in a UINavigationController
       • Connect it to the AMSlideMenuLeftTableViewController or AMSlideMenuRightTableViewController with custom segue          AMSlideMenuContentSegue and set some identifier.
      If you want to use dynamic cells , then you have to perform segues in -tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method yourself.

6.. In MainVC.m override these methods and return segue identifiers that you setted in previous step: 

-(NSString *)segueIdentifierForIndexPathInLeftMenu:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
-(NSString *)segueIdentifierForIndexPathInRightMenu:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
If you want to use multiple storyboards, or just want to use storyboard ids instead of segues, then override these methods:

-(UINavigationController *)navigationControllerForIndexPathInLeftMenu:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
-(UINavigationController *)navigationControllerForIndexPathInRightMenu:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
Thats it, you are done.
```

I would check the sample project to get an idea how to approach what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by Explicitly loading a segue like this

```
[self.mainSlideMenu.leftMenu performSegueWithIdentifier:@"tipsSegue" sender:sender];
```